# Convert Opus (.ogg) to PCM (.wav) in .NET

Tags: c#, wav, naudio, ogg, opus

I have a file .ogg and i need to convert it to .wav. I'm tryng to use [Opus.Net](https://github.com/DevJohnC/Opus.NET) (that use NAudio) but i get this exception in OpusDecoder.Decode():

> "System.Exception: 'Decoding failed - InvalidPacket'"

This is the code:

```
byte[] audioBynary = File.ReadAllBytes($"{filePath}{fileOgg}");

_decoder = OpusDecoder.Create(48000, 1);
var pcmBinary = _decoder.Decode(audioBynary, audioBynary.Length, out int decodedLenght);

WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile($"{filePath}{fileWav}", new WaveFileReader(new MemoryStream(pcmBinary)));
```

Comment: That project looks like it's no longer updated. You could try Logan Stromberg's version instead, which works well for me: https://github.com/lostromb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works for me, I read the ogg/opus file with Concentus (install Concentus & Concentus.OggFile from nuget), copy it's bytes to a memoryStream and then use it to create a RawSourceWaveStream.
I can get an ISampleProvider from the RawSourceWaveStream, which is what you need to feed
WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16.

Voilá

```
        using Concentus.Oggfile;
        using Concentus.Structs;

        //...

     public static void ConvertOggToWav()
     {
            var filePath = $@"C:\Users\blabla\foo\bar\";
            var fileOgg = "testAudio.ogg";
            var fileWav = "testAudio.wav";

        using (FileStream fileIn = new FileStream($"{filePath}{fileOgg}", FileMode.Open))
        using (MemoryStream pcmStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            OpusDecoder decoder = OpusDecoder.Create(48000, 1);
            OpusOggReadStream oggIn = new OpusOggReadStream(decoder, fileIn);
            while (oggIn.HasNextPacket)
            {
                short[] packet = oggIn.DecodeNextPacket();
                if (packet != null)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < packet.Length; i++)
                    {
                        var bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(packet[i]);
                        pcmStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    }
                }
            }
            pcmStream.Position = 0;
            var wavStream = new RawSourceWaveStream(pcmStream, new WaveFormat(48000, 1));
            var sampleProvider = wavStream.ToSampleProvider(); 
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile16($"{filePath}{fileWav}", sampleProvider);
         }
      }
```

Comment: It's work fine, it is exactly what i need! Thank you!

Comment: Would you by any chance know how to do this in java in Android Studio?