# Convert ogg audio file to opus audio file

Tags: c#, audio, .net-core, c#-4.0

I am recording ogg file in Html5. It is recording fine. But i want to convert OGG file OPUS format file. I have tried so many libraries which is not working as expected.

The following code returning error like below,

The frame size must be one of the following: 2.5, 5, 10, 20, 40 or 60.
Parameter name: length.

```
using (FileStream fileIn = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Downloads\1.ogg", FileMode.Open))
using (MemoryStream pcmStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    short[] packets = new short[0];
    var decoder = Concentus.Structs.OpusDecoder.Create(48000, 2);
    var oggIn = new Concentus.Oggfile.OpusOggReadStream(decoder, fileIn);
    while (oggIn.HasNextPacket)
    {
        short[] packet = oggIn.DecodeNextPacket();
        if (packet != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < packet.Length; i++)
            {
                var oggbytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(packet[i]);
                pcmStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
            if (packets != null && packets.Length > 0)
                Combine(packets, packet);
            else
            {
                packets = new short[packet.Length];
                packets = packet;
            }
        }
    }
    pcmStream.Position = 0;

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        pcmStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
        var encoder = new OpusDotNet.OpusEncoder(OpusDotNet.Application.Audio, 48000, 2);
        opbytes = new byte[packets.Length];
        var obytes = encoder.Encode(memoryStream.ToArray(), packets.Length, out int encodedLength);
        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"C:\Users\Downloads\new.opus", memoryStream.ToArray());
    }
}
```

Please help me to convert OGG audio file to OPUS audio file in c#.

Thanks in advance,
Mani

Comment: HI @Llama, Thanks for your response. I am building asp.net mvc application and i am recoding audio using javascript and trying to decode OGG to OPUS in my controller class.

Comment: Removed Asp.Net tag

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950935/1253500