# Convert oga to wav using NAudio VorbisWaveReader exception: could not initialize container

Tags: c#, .net-core, naudio, vorbis

I'm trying to convert a oga audio file downloded from whatsapp into a wav file.
I'm using Naudio to perform the conversion.
This is my code:

```
public void TestConvert()
        {
            string fileoga = @"C:\1.ogg";
            string filewav = @"C:\1.wav";
            var vorbis = new VorbisWaveReader(fileoga);
            WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(filewav, vorbis);
            return;
        }
```

When trying to `CreateWaveFile` I get the following exception: Could not initialize container!

I tried with `using` and without and all the other suggestions online.
Will appriciate your help.

Comment: I was in the same situation, what you need is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50950935/1253500